# Изменение размера вектора

Tags: c++, vector

Слышал, что если делать в вектор `push_back`, то если у него не хватает внутреннего буфера, то он увеличивается в 1.5 раза. Правда ли?

Будет ли тоже самое происходить когда я буду делать последовательно `resize`:

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    b.resize(i+1);
    b[i] = i;
}
```

Написал код, который сравнивает время исполнения каждой из версий. Вторая получается немного медленнее.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int N = 10000000;

    clock_t tStart;

    vector<int> a;

    tStart = clock();
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) a.push_back(i);
    printf("Time taken: %.4f sec\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    vector<int> b;

    tStart = clock();
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        b.resize(i+1);
        b[i] = i;
    }
    printf("Time taken: %.4f sec\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

Пример вывода на [ideone](http://ideone.com/OxjpAP):

```
Time taken: 0.0649 sec
Time taken: 0.0692 sec
```

Comment: Не совсем правда — это нигде не прописано, но разные реализации используют различные коэффициенты увеличения размера, при нехватке места в текущем выделенном пространстве. Все известные мне реализации увеличивают размер на число большее, чем требуется для одной операции помещения в контейнер.

Comment: При `resize` реализация скорее всего вмешиваться не будет и будет выделять ровно столько, сколько попросили. `resize` и `reserve` в цикле является пессимизацией и ошибкой.

Answer (score -1):

Лучше для добавления элементов брать не vector, а list или unordered_set.
Вектор хорошо удаляет и добавляет элементы только в конец. В остальных случаях на
сколько-то больших данных вектор начинает двигать элементы и это может плохо сказаться на производительности. Можно конечно не передвигать при удалении, но тогда нарушается порядок элементов.

Вектор может выигрывать на малых тестах, но это пока в кэш данные влезут. Если вектор 10-100 малых элементов, то он быстрее будет, а может и нет, это от очень многих факторов зависит.

Вобщем есть дофига вариаций, когда что быстрее.

Можно запустить вот это и узнать что происходит с вектором.

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
b.resize(i+1);
cout<<i+1<<" "<<b.capacity()<<endl;
}
```

В одной онлайн IDE

1 1

2 2

3 4

4 4

5 8

...

16 16
17 32

```
b.resize(i+1);
b[i] = i;
```

Два раза присваивается значение сначала 0 потом цифра наверное поэтому дольше.

Comment: вот честно 1 фраза убила. С чего это вдруг list быстрее оказывается?

Comment: Есть золотое правило: всегда бери вектор, пока не доказана необходимость брать другой контейнер.

Comment: @ixSci откуда такое правило?) Мне казалось золотое правило - сначала думать какие операции будут, а потом контейнер выбирать.

Comment: @pavel, вектор, как правило, оказывается быстрее других контейнеров, даже в тех случаях, когда кажется, что другой контейнер подходит лучше. За последние три года конференций CppCon этот вопрос там поднимался неоднократно.

Comment: list работает стабильнее чем вектор(не даёт неожиданных провисаний) поэтому он лучше.

Comment: @ixSci для программ реального времени тоже подойдёт вектор?

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, да.

Comment: @pavel например, элементы списка могут быть разбросаны по памяти, а это не очень дружелюбно по отношению к кешу.

Comment: По моему, надо все таки сначала думать, а потом уже выбирать контейнер. В пользу списка можно отнести значительно меньшее число копирований объектов контейнера при его расширении (move-семантика от этого не спасет). Лучше всего предполагать использование списка, т.е. ориентироваться на работу с итераторами, а уже сам контейнер после этого поменять будет несложно. Профилировщик покажет, какой контейнер эффективнее. Только надо учитывать, что он это покажет на конкретных тестах. Вполне можно подобрать примеры, когда разное тестовое воздействие покажет плюсы как для вектора так и для списка.